# Launch APK Installer Kitkat

Tags: android, android-studio

I have had this code tested & working on Lolipop , Marshmallow , Nougat , Oreo but not working on Lolipop I need help

I want to make auto-update and auto-install at once. It is local so it's non-market application.

bellow is the code.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "myapp.apk";
                MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                File newFile = new File(path);
                String ext = newFile.getName().substring(newFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.mypackage.fileProvider", newFile);
                        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, type);
                    } else {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), type);
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    Log.i("update_statut", "Error : " + anfe.getMessage());
                }
```

Here is my manifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What are your symptoms? What does Logcat show?

Comment: @CommonsWare A Dialog appears in the app : 

Parse Error : there was a problem parsing the package 

and no error in log

Comment: @CommonsWare It also happens when I open the apk directly from sd card folder .. I thinks its an issue related to kitkat api not code

Comment: Are you testing this on a device or an emulator? If it is a device, try an emulator, as perhaps there is something about that device that is causing the problem. It does not like your APK file for some reason. You might also try pulling the APK off of the device/emulator and confirming that it was not corrupted somehow (e.g., compare MD5 hashes).

Comment: @CommonsWare Im testing it on emulator , I found out that this problem is common on youtube